# WPF CollectionView/DataGrid get index of first visible item

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

is there a way to get the first visible item that is displayed to the user?

In the WinForms's `DatagridView` we had `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex`.
Is there an equivalent for the WPF variant?

I'm using a CollectionView in my ViewModel which is bound to a DataGrid in XAML.

> **Just to be clear:** I **don't** want to get the SelectedRow's index, this I
>   can already do...

**Example**
I've got 20 items in my ObservableCollection and my Datagrid can only show 13 due to size-restrictions.
Item2 was previously selected by the user and after that the user scrolled a bit down, so items 5-17 are visible.
How do I get the index of item5?

**XAML**

```
<Style x:Key="DatagridStyle" TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ColorDatagridBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserSortColumns" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderHeight" Value="25"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,5"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ItemCollection}"/>
</Style>
<DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
              Style="{StaticResource DatagridStyle}"
              util:DataGridColumnsBehavior.BindableColumns="{Binding DatagridColumns, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              EnableRowVirtualization="True">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <util:DataGridScrollBehaviour />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</DataGrid>
```

**ViewModel**

```
private ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> _datagridColumns;
private CollectionView _itemCollection;
private CollectionViewSource _itemCollectionSource;
public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> DatagridColumns
    {
        get => _datagridColumns;
        set
        {
            _datagridColumns = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public CollectionView ItemCollection
    {
        get => _itemCollection;
        set
        {
            _itemCollection = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public CollectionViewSource ItemCollectionSource
    {
        get => _itemCollectionSource;
        set
        {
            _itemCollectionSource = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    _datagridColumns = MainViewModel.GetColumns(MainViewModel.AppMode.Match);

    _itemCollectionSource = new CollectionViewSource();
    ItemCollectionSource.Source = _vml.Main.ItemList;
    _itemCollection = (CollectionView)ItemCollectionSource.View;
```

**Desired Result:**
if my view-area is ...
 - at the **top** and I add an item at the top (due to current sorting), I want my view-area to stay at the top, so I can see my new item
 - at the **bottom** and I add an item at the bottom (due to current sorting), I want my view-area to move to the 'new' bottom, so I can see my new item
 - is anywhere in the middle, I want to keep looking at the same X items

I can access the SortOrder via my CollectionView, but in order to determine where my view-area needs to be moved, I do need to know, where my view-area currently is (top, middle, bottom)

Comment: Depends on what you use? `GridView` in a `ListView` or `DataGrid`? Some xaml would be useful. Is there any particular reason why you would want the visible element? There are always triggers that you could use.

Comment: based on the currently visible area I'd like to decide, if and how I want to scroll automatically.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve that makes knowing this index value necessary?

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything about your requirements. Do you want to scroll to that item because it is connected somehow to the first item or is it because you just want to implement some smart scrolling (which will bite you back)?

Comment: It's just used to determine, where my view-area is currently, so I can then decide which sort of "smart-scrolling" I need to apply

Comment: Did you find anything on this yet?  I've got a similar need, I want the top item visible in an itemscontrol wrapped inside a scroll viewer.  This seems to be something available in android, but I can't find anything in WPF where the items that are scrolled into view are tracked.

Answer (score 2):

For my problem (a scrollviewer with an items control) I found the solution was to capture the scroll changed event and use it.  Since a DataGrid has a scroll viewer I think you can do the same, or instead of scroll changed use the same logic elsewhere that makes the most sense.  So in the window code behind:

```
    private void dgScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)sender;
        foreach (ObservableFlatObservations o in dg.Items)
        {
            UIElement v = (UIElement)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(o);
            GeneralTransform childTransform = v.TransformToAncestor((ScrollViewer)sender);
            Rect rectangle = childTransform.TransformBounds(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), v.RenderSize));
            Rect result = Rect.Intersect(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), ((ScrollViewer)sender).RenderSize), rectangle);
            if (result != Rect.Empty)
            {
                //This one is visible so do some stuff
                return;// i is the index of this item
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```

And in the datagrid xaml definition:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MainDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          ItemsSource="{Binding oFObs.View}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentObs, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
          ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="dgScrollChanged">
```

I haven't tested this with my datagrid quite yet, but this method worked well for my original case.  Note my data element names are not mapped to your question, but I think you can modify this to work with what you have.

After actually trying this, it turns out to perhaps be simpler.  In the event handler only rows that are visible in the grid will return a value from the ContainerFromItem call because the datagrid virtualizes the contents.  So I think if you do something like this you can find the first visible index in the datagrid:

```
private void dgScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)sender;
    foreach (GetFlatObservationsResult o in dg.ItemsSource)
    {
        DataGridRow v = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(o);
        if(v!=null)
        {
            //i is the index of the first visable row
            //do some stuff
            return;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add `SelectedIndex="{Binding SelIndex}"` attribute in the collection tag.

Where SelIndex will be the property in your ViewModel file bounded to this attribute.

Comment: as already stated in the question: I don't want the the index of the selectedRow. I want to get the index of the first visibleRow