# How to create solid background with rounded corners under rows only in DataGrid in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridrow

I wish to make datagrid with solid background with rounded corners under rows only. Header row must be without background.

I tried several options to reach this by (row / header / datagrid) styles, but it wasn't successfull.

I guess the best way is using DataTrigger with binding to DataGrid row order (one template for first and last row and second template for middle rows), but I can't find row order property. I'd appreciate all the help.

It must look like this.

[image: 1]

Comment: Put your DataGrid into a Border. You can set CornerRadius and Background properties on it. [Border](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.border?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Comment: This doesn't help, background is under whole datagrid. It seems you read my question inattentively.

Comment: Will you have more rows than fit in the view? If so. what happens when you get a slider on your scrollviewer? That will be rectangular of course, rather like the scroller in this edge browser I'm using.

Comment: I think you pretty much have to do this using the datatrigger you mention due to the scroller. This is a bit of a complication since the area you might otherwise want to put a rounded border round is a scrollcontentpresenter. And of course you have the issue of what happens when you select a row.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53740330/wpf-collectionview-datagrid-get-index-of-first-visible-item

Comment: @Andy, This datagrid must fit strictly two rows. I will work around your idea, thanks

Comment: If you just want 2 rows then I'm not sure a datagrid is worth the complications it introduces. Just a grid with columns for the headers and an itemscontrol with an itemtemplate has a grid and columns per row would work.  You then have fine control of the UI without the complications a datagrid introduces.  Use SharedSizeGroup to make columns in "header" and rows the same width.

Comment: It would be best solution, but I have different templates for different tables and one characteristic unite those tables - background under rows only. So it would be easier to make one template for all ones in my case.

Answer (score 0):

you have to overwrite the datagrid's template (it sounds a lot more complex than it actually is):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <!-- extra attributes as example, but you can tweak whatever you want in the template, what is important is the "CornerRadius" here -->
                <Border Name="Border"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        CornerRadius="3">
                    <ScrollViewer Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false" CanContentScroll="True" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="true">
                        <!-- here you can also overwrite the Scrollviewer's Template if you wish -->
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

this style should go in /theme/Generic.xaml or in your app.xaml (or in any xaml dictionary you want, as long as it is referenced correctly)

Comment: I tried your idea, it's almost successfell except for header row - it became invisible.

Comment: ah yes, you might need to tweak the template a little. Have a look there for the OG template of the datagrid, as reference (what I used for my answer) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/datagrid-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8.

you are probably missing the <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" ... > part (I did not need it in my case, hence the omission). Or it might be that you need the whole scrollviewer template.

Comment: thanks, you helped me to achieve my goal

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. I have taken default datagrid template and put ItemsPresenter into border with needed parameters. Then I applied this template to datagrid.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="dg_solid_without_header" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
            <Border x:Name="border"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                <Border.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                </Border.Background>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                      (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer"
                        Focusable="false"
                        Background="Black">
                    <ScrollViewer.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter"
                                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                                  Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, 
                      ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, 
                      Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, 
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />

                                <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                          Grid.Row="1"
                                          CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" />

                                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                             Grid.Column="2"
                             Grid.Row="1"
                             Orientation="Vertical"
                             ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                             Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                             Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                             Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, 
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>

                                <Grid Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="2">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, 
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Orientation="Horizontal"
                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                               Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ScrollViewer.Template>
                    <Border Background="#0F1F2F" BorderBrush="#114B6F" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="8">
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </Border>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>



<DataGrid Name="dg_upper_bracket_results_table_cla" Margin="243 20 243 0" Style="{StaticResource new_CLA_table_style}" Template="{StaticResource dg_solid_without_header}" ItemsSource="{Binding UpperBracketTable}">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <StaticResource ResourceKey="dgtcPosition_new_cla"/>
                                <StaticResource ResourceKey="dgtcPlayerWithDivision_new_cla"/>
                                <StaticResource ResourceKey="dgtcTeam_new_cla"/>
                                <StaticResource ResourceKey="dgtcWins"/>
                                <StaticResource ResourceKey="dgtcDraws"/>
                                <StaticResource ResourceKey="dgtcLosses"/>
                                <StaticResource ResourceKey="dgtcGoals"/>
                                <StaticResource ResourceKey="dgtcPoints"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource default_datagridrow_style}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                        </DataGrid>
```